# Jquery tab panel - prevent active tab moving

Tags: jquery

I've made a simple tab panel using Jquery, it works fine apart from when you click on the active tab the  panel starts changing and I don't know how to fix it. I want it so that when the active tab is clicked nothing happens.

Thanks

codepen : http://codepen.io/MarkShakespeare/pen/qERMZo

html:

```
<div id="tab-panel">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li data-panel-id = "panel1" class ="active">Panel 1</li>
    <li data-panel-id = "panel2">panel 2</li>
    <li data-panel-id = "panel3">panel 3</li>
    <li data-panel-id ="panel4">panel 4</li>  
  </ul>

<div id="panel1" class ="active-panel">
  content 1 <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/> 
</div>
<div id="panel2" class ="panel">
  content 2 <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/> 
</div> 
<div id="panel3" class ="panel">
  content 3 <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/> 
</div>
<div id="panel4" class ="panel">
  content 4 <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/>
  content <br/> 
</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
#tab-panel ul {
  display: block;
}

#tab-panel ul li {
  display: inline;
  background: pink;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tab-panel ul li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#tab-panel .tabs li.active {
  background-color: red;
}

#tab-panel .panel {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;

}

.active-panel {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#tab-panel .tabs li').on('click', function() {
  var $panelToShow = $(this).attr('data-panel-id');
  var $activePanel = $('#tab-panel .tabs li.active');

  $($activePanel).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#tab-panel .active-panel').slideUp(300);
  $('#' + $panelToShow).slideDown(300, function() {
    $(this).addClass('active-panel');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following logic:

```
$('#tab-panel .tabs').on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function() {
  var panelToShow = $(this).data('panelId');
  var $activePanel = $('#tab-panel .tabs li.active');      
  $(this).add($activePanel).toggleClass('active');
   $('#tab-panel .active-panel').slideUp(300);
  $('#' + panelToShow).slideDown(300, function() {
    $(this).addClass('active-panel');
  });
});
```

### -DEMO-